# Copy column based on cell value

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I would like to make a VBA script that can copy a column based on a cell value to another sheet.

So "SheetA" has in cell A1 the value "3-2014" (month value can change)

Sheet "SheetB" contains the database, that looks something like this:

2-2014     3-2014     4-2014

value a    value b    value c

value d    value e    value f

So now i would like to copy column that contains "3-2014" to sheet "SheetC".

The result would be in "SheetC, column 1"

3-2014

value b

value e

I looked and tried but couldn't find the answer, really hope that someone can help me.

Best wishes for 2015 and thnx!

Kind regards,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

you could use HLOOKUP.

In "SheetC, column 1" the forumulas would be

```
=HLOOKUP(SheetA!$A$1,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,1,FALSE)
=HLOOKUP(SheetA!$A$1,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,2,FALSE)
=HLOOKUP(SheetA!$A$1,SheetB!$A$1:$C$3,3,FALSE)
```

Yes?

I know this doesn't COPY the column, but I suspect this is what you wanted?

Or here's the VBA

```
 sub a

    Dim ashtEntry As Worksheet
    Dim ashtDatabase As Worksheet
    Dim ashtResult As Worksheet

    Dim DbCell As Range
    Dim ResultCell As Range
    Dim rngDatabase As Range
    Dim rngEntry As Range

    Set ashtEntry = Worksheets("SheetA")
    Set ashtDatabase = Worksheets("SheetB")
    Set ashtResult = Worksheets("SheetC")

    Set rngEntry = ashtEntry.Range("A1")
    Set rngDatabase = ashtDatabase.Range("$A$1:$C$3")

    For Each DbCell In rngDatabase.Rows(1).Cells 

        If DbCell.Value = rngEntry.Value Then

            With ashtResult.Range("$A$1:$A$3")
                .Cells(1) = DbCell.Value
                .Cells(2) = DbCell.Offset(1, 0).Value
                .Cells(3) = DbCell.Offset(2, 0).Value
            End With

            MsgBox "OK"

            Exit For

        End If

    Next


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It has to be done using VBA?

I'd use in SheetC, A1:

```
=INDEX(SheetB!$A1:$C1,MATCH(SheetA!$A$1,SheetB!$A$1:$C$1,0))
```

and drag it down...

Hope it works!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your suggestion. I have been workt on my issue some more and came up with the following solution;

```
  Sub ImportFromDatabase()

    strSearch1 = Sheets("manual").Range("C11")

    Const fromFile = "otherfile.xlsm"

    Dim srcBook As Workbook
    Set srcBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(fromFile, _
        UpdateLinks:=False, _
        ReadOnly:=True, _
        AddToMRU:=False)

         Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    With wrkbk
        Set Value1 = srcBook.Sheets("DAx_data").Rows(3).Find(What:=strSearch1, LookIn:=xlValues, _
            LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

           srcBook.Sheets("DAx_data").Columns(Value1.Column).Copy
           ThisWorkbook.Sheets("source").Columns(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:=xlNone


         Application.DisplayAlerts = True
         Application.CutCopyMode = False

    End With
        srcBook.Close False

    End Sub
```

It's not pretty, and I'm sure that that this can be made better by using a Range but my knowledge of VBA is not that good.

Jim